# NSHostingController subclass type including generics

Tags: generics, swiftui

This is a syntax problem. I am happily following along Daniel Steinberg's excellent SwiftUI Kickstart book, and a little while along, we have `struct CheckerBoard` which later becomes
`struct CheckerBoard<A> where A: View`
So far so good. If I use it in a SwiftUI-only app, as the book intended, @main instantiates an instance of Checkerboard and all is well.

If I want to use it in a storyboard app, I need to use an NSHostingController, and in order to do so, you need to specify a type.

Not a problem for
`class SwiftUIHostingController: NSHostingController<CheckerBoard>`

but a big problem when I try to amend this for `struct CheckerBoard<A> where A: View`

This is where I struggle (I've tried looking at a lot of SwiftUI tutorials, generics tutorials, and various descriptions of the problem, all without success. 'Generics' and 'where' are not good things to google for).

Fixit suggests

`class SwiftUIHostingController: NSHostingController<CheckerBoard<<#A: View#>>>` but that's as far as I get. I cannot work out what to replace `A: View` with.

`NSHostingController<CheckerBoard<A where A: View>>` fails with "Expected '>' to complete generic argument list", as does `NSHostingController<CheckerBoard<A> where A: View>` and `NSHostingController<CheckerBoard<A: View>>`.

Me wanting to use a View with a generic property appears to be rare enough that this has thrown the compiler completely: not only do I not get a useful hint for code completion in NSHostingController, but the PreviewProvider creates a rather panicked error of "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project".

(This really should have the tag 'NSHostingController' but I cannot add it myself.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need another level of specification, because only concrete controller can be  placed into storyboard, something like

`class TextCheckboardController: NSHostingController<CheckerBoard<Text>>`

, for each specific `A` in corresponding place.

Comment: The CheckerBoard struct cannot be downcast like that, it's type is _CheckerBoard<A> where A: View_, and there is no error-free way of declaring this. What this seems to imply is that the flexibility of SwiftUI is limited greatly when used with storyboards.

Comment: NSHostingController cannot be used with not a view struct, ie NSHostingController<T>, where T must be a View, independently if it is concrete or generic type.